# Change Cassandra configuration on runtime in Storm

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-storm

I'm using the storm cassad [storm-cassandra](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/storm-cassandra.html) It is configured and working, But I have two issues:

1. I have 2 data centers and if one of them fail I want to load the information to the other one. The question is how to change the configuration in the cluster on runtime.
2. I want to change the consistency level in cassandra on runtime

Both problems are related on the change of configuration is Storm cassandra

Comment: Regarding your questions, 1. If one of the DC fails then you wanted to load the information to other DC. What is the information you want to load?. Is it in the client (Apache-Storm) or in the Cassandra? You don't need to load information in Cassandra, since based on your replication factor the data will already be in sync.